# ServiceStack - Timeout Expired caused by max application pool size

Tags: servicestack, idisposable

I'm using ServiceStack's funq and I have code below in my AppHost file. The API hit timeout expired error due to application pool size hits maximum limit.

```
    var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(string.Empty, SqlServerDialect.Provider);

... 

// Loop to get multiple different country connection string
foreach (string server in countryCodeList)
{
    dbFactory.RegisterConnection(server, connectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider);
}

this.RequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpRes, requestDto) =>
{
    requestInfo = requestDto.Dump();
    ...
    container.Register<IReferenceRepository>(c => new ReferenceRepository(dbFactory, baseModel.db_country_code));
    container.Register<ICompanyRepository>(c => new CompanyRepository(dbFactory, baseModel.db_country_code));
    ...
});
```

I have implemented IDisposable in my Repository base class. But it does not seem dispose the connection at the end of each request. In the perfmon.exe can see the NumberOfPooledConnections is keep increasing for each request without dropping.

Codes in Repository bass class:

```
public class Repository : IDisposable
{
    protected IDbConnectionFactory dbFactory { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    private IDbConnection db;

    public Repository(IDbConnectionFactory dbConnectionFactory, string countryCode)
    {
        this.dbFactory = dbConnectionFactory;
        this.CountryCode = countryCode;
    }

    protected virtual IDbConnection Db(string connectionKey)
    {
        return db ?? (db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection(connectionKey));
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        if (db != null)
            db.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Just wondering if adding **ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request)** into container.Register part will it helps?

Can anyone guide me if I'm doing in the correct way? Thanks in advance.

Edited: The API request will call from one service to the other and it gets data from different repository.

Comment: (The connections *are* disposed of appropriately, right? It should likely be handled through the bundled IoC container..)

Comment: @user2864740 Not really. For an API request, it will trigger to the other service and get the data from different repository. Not sure if this cause the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All dependencies in ServiceStack should be registered in `AppHost.Configure()` which runs once on StartUp and should be considered immutable thereafter.

You should not be **registering** dependencies in a RequestFilter (which gets run on each request).

`OrmLiteConnectionFactory` (like all factories in ServiceStack) are designed to be registered as a singleton, which is also the default lifetime in Funq, i.e:

```
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(
    c => new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connString, SqlServerDialect.Provider));
```

You can then resolve it from the IOC in order to register your named connections, e.g:

```
var factory=(OrmLiteConnectionFactory)container.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>();
foreach (string server in countryCodeList)
{
    factory.RegisterConnection(server, connString, SqlServerDialect.Provider);
}
```

All other dependencies like your repositories should also be registered in `AppHost.Configure()`. If it implements `IDisposable` and has ReuseScope of `None` or `Request` it will be disposed of at the end of the request.

#### Using Request Data to Create Dependencies

As dependencies needs to be registered on StartUp it doesn't have access to Request data. If that's what's needed it needs to be passed in at run-time.

You can reduce boilerplate by adding it to a base Service class, e.g:

```
public abstract class AppServiceBase : Service
{
    public IDbConnectionFactory DbFactory 
    { 
        get { return TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>(); }
    }

    ReferenceRepository refRepo;
    public ReferenceRepository ReferenceRepo
    {
        get
        {
            if (refRepo == null)
                refRepo = new ReferenceRepository(
                    DbFactory.OpenDbConnection(Request.Param("c_code")));

            return refRepo;
        }
    }

    public override Dispose()
    {
        base.Dispose();

        if (refRepo != null)
           refRepo.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Which your services can then access like a normal dependency, i.e:

```
public class MyService : AppServiceBase
{
    public object Get(Request request)
    {
        var foo = ReferenceRepo.GetById(request.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: May I know how to get the DbFactory in AppServiceBase class?

Comment: @aQing ok yeah example updated. You can use `TryResolve<T>` to resolve dependencies from the Service class. This is also how [Service class retrieves its IDbConnection](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Service.cs#L71).

Comment: Deployed the codes to production and problem solved. Thanks @mythz for the prompt support and solution! =)